# Can I use nudity (in a non-sexual/erotic context) in a children's story?

Tags: children, story

Is it possible for a story intended for children to have a scene with several naked children? There is nothing erotic in this, they're just washing in a public bath, this is depicted as a normal domestic situation. This moment is important for the plot because here they are introduced to an important character, who is actually a magical creature that lives in this bath. Would this be considered a children's book?

Comment: Is this a picture book or are there only written descriptions?

Comment: What country do you intend to publish in? Some are a bit more over-reactive than others. Also consider that drawings needn't be anatomically correct, and/or you can use strategically placed objects to cover up parts people would object to being shown.

Comment: Russia, Only written description

Comment: I would recomend asking this on the Law Stack Exchange since finding someone who can speak to your jurisdiction in Writing Stack may be tough (I'm not certain there will be an immediate helpful answer there, but the odds are better).  I can say in the United States a written depiction of children in the bath tub passes without comment.  Harry Potter has a scene where a 14 year old Harry is bathing that passed without incident.  And he was naked as a Ghost Girl from an earlier book walks in on him and admits she didn't see anything after tries to cover up more.

Comment: Generally, in U.S. law, generally the image is only illegal if it is of a real person and is done purely for sexual reasons (depictions  of naked children in medical text are fine for documenting injuries so long as the subject's identity is not revealed in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion (and I understand this is opinion-based rather than legal question), this would be totally fine as long as you are not dwelling on children's nudity.

For example, in "My Neighbor Totoro" (which is not even a book, but animated movie, which raises the stakes), young girls are bathing together naked. Moreover, they are bathing together with their father (apparently also naked), which is certainly raising some viewers' eyebrows outside of Japan. And yet this is all considered fine, because the scene is not sexualized in any way.

Comment: Yeah there are lots of children's stories involving nakedness, for instance Hans Christian Andersen's The Emperor's New Clothes.